# Why execute command in a Rails migration doesn't show up in schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a project that is using `execute` command to directly perform some migration commands on the database, but I don't see these commands in the schema.rb. That makes me wonder whether execute commands are excluded from an ordinary schema dump? There is nothing about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the standard database structure is stored in schema.rb.  Depending on what you are doing with the `execute` calls, you may have better luck dumping your database structure in SQL format. You can change the schema format in application.rb:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

You can other helpful information about schemas in [Schema Dumping and You](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you)